# Use default ruby version in Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, ruby-1.9.3

My default and current version of ruby is 1.9.3. It's actually the only version that appears when I run `rvm list` so I don't see how I can be messing that part up. I did follow [this](http://upstre.am/blog/2011/07/sublime-text-2-with-rvm-on-osx/)
tutorial that I found here, but it just seemed to break everything. I keep getting "No such file or directory" for all the variations of the fix I see, even the in the comments. I am on a Mac, please let me know what other information I need to post here to help you figure out how I'm breaking things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always edit which `ruby` is used by editing your Build command preferences:

```
subl ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/Ruby/Ruby.sublime-build
```

Change the default `"ruby"` to whatever path you require. The version you're using at any given time can be discovered with:

```
which ruby
```

Alternatively you can just link to the default which is often located at `/opt/local/rvm/bin/ruby`.