# undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object when running build from sublime

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've got everything working from my command line so I can run `ruby myfile` and it works. But when I try to run it from within sublime I get

```
undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object
```

Anyone know what is missing in my sublime setup? I am using OS X and has rvm installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because sublime runs 1.8.7 version of ruby. You could change it. [Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830607/use-default-ruby-version-in-sublime-text-2).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could just use 'require' and it should work just fine. I think 'require_relative' is only available for ruby 1.9+